# How to telnet login to email server as administrator?

Tags: email, telnet

There is a administrator interface for our webmail, where we supply our administrator name and password. In there we can see user information and system log etc., but it only shows very limited information and a recent, short, range of time.

The email server is remotely hosted. To read more info on the server log, I will have to telnet. I can telnet to read and sent email but how to telnet as administrator to read the log? I telnet the server as usual and supply my admin name and password, but I keep getting authentication failure error.

Comment: Don't forget to EHLO!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to speak to the people who run the server and ask them if it can be done, and how.  Nobody here knows how your server is configured, and there is no such thing as "a standard server".

Odds are, though, that you can't, because nobody sane would allow telnet to a server over the Internet in this day and age.  SSH is ubiquitous, effective, and significantly more secure, and *may* be available on the system.

Really, though, you need to ask the people who run your server.